# What is the difference between VMware vSphere and vSphere Hypervisor?

Tags: esxi

What is the difference between VMware:

```
1. vSphere
2. vSphere Hypervisor
3. vSphere ESXi
```

I've installed Hypervisor, but seems I've been forced to install evaluation of vSphere. Do I need it? I only want a soft like Oracle VirtualBox, but on server. No advanced monitoring, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vSphere is the client and ESXI is the server.
vSphere Hypervisor is just the free version of vSphere.
You build your VMs in ESXI and vsphere will allow you  to remote to them.

Answer (score 1):

While I am a newbie when it comes to VMware, but I chanced upon this question, while looking for an answer, so consider the answer as (not yet) not authoritative.

My understanding is that "vSphere" is a brand name for the suite of software products, that allow an entity (enterprise, hosting co. etc.) to create cloud-computing infrastructure, using virtualization technologies, but at the same time giving tools to configure and manage cluster of hosts running hypervisor and VMs (on the hypervisor).

Also, my understanding is vSphere Hypervisor includes ESXi for the server virtualization, but bundled with just enough management tools to manage a single instance of ESXi, i.e. it is not cluster-aware, and can manage only 1 host. That single host, however can run many VMs.

The suite, is extended by additional optional (& licensed) products that take care of functionality s.a. Application Discovery, Data Protection, Replication, Security.